# Why is the 2nd Command inside a Connection does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I'm trying to do a test in two tables based on what the user entered in the login TextBox, So I test the LoginName if it is in Table "Redacteur"; else I make a new Command that will look inside another table "Membres".
Problem is: the command works when I enter a loginName that is in the table "Redacteur", but Once I enter a loginName that belongs to the Membres's table It doesn't redirect me to the page I'm requesting inside the code. I think it doesn't even enter the Else section.

```
using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Redacteurs where RedCode= @lg", connect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lg", TextLogIn.Text);
    connect.Open();
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        rd.Read();
        Session["code"] = rd["RedCode"].ToString();
        Session["loginname"] = TextLogIn.Text;
        Session["pass"] = TextPass.Value;
        Response.Redirect("RedacteurPage.aspx?Redact=" 
            + Session["loginname"].ToString());
        rd.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Membres where LoginMembre = @lm", connect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lm", TextLogIn.Text);
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd2.HasRows)
        {
            rd2.Read();
            Session["code"] = rd2["MembreCode"].ToString();
            Session["loginname"] = TextLogIn.Text;
            Session["pass"] = TextPass.Value;
            Response.Redirect("ProductCatalogue.aspx?user=" + rd2["FullName"]);
            rd2.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're opening the door for SQL Injection here.

Comment: `I think it doesn't even enter the Else section` You should verify this using the debugger

Comment: Try changing the line `cmd = new SqlCommand(...)` to `cmd.CommandText = "NEW SQL"`

Comment: @Kramb I'm using Parameters to prevent injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close/dispose the first command before you can execute one on the same connection.

The quick-and-dirty (i.e. works but not recommended) solution would be to have `rd.Close()` in the first line of your `else` block.

Comment: @Kramb It's a parameterized query - where exactly is the injection vulnerability?